# timeslots in database are being duplicated by bookings php code instead of skipped

Tags: php, fullcalendar

I am using Fullcalendar 4 to create a bookings system for clients to book callout slots for equipment repairs.

So far with the help of a user on here I have managed to get the calendar object to populate the booked slots into the calendar and i have almost got it to add in the free unbooked slots too using a seperate eventSouce and checking in php on the serverside which slots in a day are taken and skipping them.

**$cDate** is the DateTime converted start date from the request sent by Fullcalendar.

**$eDate** is the DateTime converted end date from the request sent by Fullcalendar.

**$daysInRange** is a datediff variable that i worked out further up in the page to see how many days there are between $cDate and $eDate.

typical url is as follows from the ajax request:

getBookings.php?start=2020-06-05T00%3A00%3A00&end=2020-06-05T00%3A00%3A00&timeZone=Europe%2FLondon

```
$bookingStart = new DateTime( $_GET[ 'start' ] );
$bookingEnd = new DateTime( $_GET[ 'end' ] );

//Get The Start Date/Time seperately and End Date/Time Seperately.
$startdate = date_format( $bookingStart, 'Y-m-d' );
$starttime = date_format( $bookingStart, 'H:i:s' );
$enddate = date_format( $bookingEnd, 'Y-m-d' );
$endtime = date_format( $bookingEnd, 'H:i:s' );
```

my php code is:

```
$cDate = $bookingStart;
$eDate = $bookingEnd;
$slotBooked = true;

if ( count( $bookingResult ) > 0 ) {

       foreach ( $bookingResult as $bookingRes ) {

       //For this result we need to check each slot for the whole day and see
       //if there is a booking in any of the slots.
       ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
       //Create a variable with the bookings date and start of timeslot
       //then create one with bookings date and end time
       //Then we can see if the timeslot on the date is already booked.
       ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

       $dbSlotStart = new DateTime( $bookingRes[ 'bookingstarttime' ] );
       $dbSlotEnd = new DateTime( $bookingRes[ 'bookingendtime' ] );
       $dbDate = new DateTime( $bookingRes[ 'bookingdate' ] );

       for ( $i = 0; $i <= $daysInRange; $i++ ) {

       //for the current slot 
        foreach ( $freeSlots as $slot ) {

            $slotStart = new DateTime( $slot[ 'start' ] );
            $slotEnd = new DateTime( $slot[ 'end' ] );

            if ( $dbDate == $cDate ) {

            //Db Date Matches The Current Date We Are Creating Slots For.
            //Next Check If The Current Slot Is Taken.
            if ( $dbSlotStart == $slotStart && $dbSlotEnd == $slotEnd ) {

            //This slot is already booked so we can skip this slot.


            } else {

            $bookingsAsJSON[ 'title' ] = 'Unbooked Timeslot';
            $bookingsAsJSON[ 'start' ] = $cDate->format( 'Y-m-d' ) . ' ' . $slotStart->format( "H:i:s" );
            $bookingsAsJSON[ 'end' ] = $cDate->format( "Y-m-d" ) . ' ' . $slotEnd->format( "H:i:s" );
            $bookingsAsJSON[ 'extendedProps' ][ 'bookingActualDate' ] = $cDate->format( "Y-m-d" );
            $bookingsAsJSON[ 'extendedProps' ][ 'bookingActualStartTime' ] = $slotStart->format( "H:i:s" );
            $bookingsAsJSON[ 'extendedProps' ][ 'bookingActualEndTime' ] = $slotEnd->format( "H:i:s" );
            $calendarEvents[] = $bookingsAsJSON;
            }


            } else {
            //Date does not match the date we are checking so slot is free.
            $bookingsAsJSON[ 'title' ] = 'Unbooked Timeslot';
            $bookingsAsJSON[ 'start' ] = $cDate->format( 'Y-m-d' ) . ' ' . $slotStart->format( "H:i:s" );
            $bookingsAsJSON[ 'end' ] = $cDate->format( "Y-m-d" ) . ' ' . $slotEnd->format( "H:i:s" );
            $bookingsAsJSON[ 'extendedProps' ][ 'bookingActualDate' ] = $cDate->format( "Y-m-d" );
            $bookingsAsJSON[ 'extendedProps' ][ 'bookingActualStartTime' ] = $slotStart->format( "H:i:s" );
            $bookingsAsJSON[ 'extendedProps' ][ 'bookingActualEndTime' ] = $slotEnd->format( "H:i:s" );
            $calendarEvents[] = $bookingsAsJSON;    
            }

        }


            //Now add 1 day to the cDate and then check if its greater than the eDate
            $cDate->modify( '+1 Day' );
            if ($cDate > $eDate) { 
            break;
            }


            }
            } 
            } else {

                for ( $i = 0; $i <= $daysInRange; $i++ ) {

                    foreach ( $freeSlots as $slot ) {

                        $slotStart = new DateTime( $slot[ 'start' ] );
                        $slotEnd = new DateTime( $slot[ 'end' ] );

                        $bookingsAsJSON[ 'title' ] = 'Unbooked Timeslot';
                        $bookingsAsJSON[ 'start' ] = $cDate->format( 'Y-m-d' ) . ' ' . $slotStart->format( "H:i:s" );
                        $bookingsAsJSON[ 'end' ] = $cDate->format( "Y-m-d" ) . ' ' . $slotEnd->format( "H:i:s" );
                        $bookingsAsJSON[ 'extendedProps' ][ 'bookingActualDate' ] = $cDate->format( "Y-m-d" );
                        $bookingsAsJSON[ 'extendedProps' ][ 'bookingActualStartTime' ] = $slotStart->format( "H:i:s" );
                            $bookingsAsJSON[ 'extendedProps' ][ 'bookingActualEndTime' ] = $slotEnd->format( "H:i:s" );
                            $calendarEvents[] = $bookingsAsJSON;
              }  


        //Now add 1 day to the cDate and then check if its greater than the eDate
                $cDate->modify( '+1 Day' );
                if ($cDate > $eDate) { 

                break;
                }
            }


            }
```

The code above sort of works, but if for example, there is a slot on 2020-06-05 at 09:00:00 - 11:00:00 and the range is 2020-06-01 to 2020-06-08 then i am getting the slot booked on the 5th at 9am to 11am as booked in red, and also as free in green.

I am not sure why i am getting this..

[image: Screenshot of the output in Fullcalendar on the page]

As you can see from the above screenshot on the 5th June at 9am to 11pm there is a booked red slot and the same slot is there again as free in green....

Any help on where im going wrong in the code would be fantastic :)

**EDIT**

As requested here is the output from $bookingRes:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'assetjobid' => '11',
    0 => '11',
    'companyid' => 'CADB-UK-0001',
    1 => 'CADB-UK-0001',
    'assetid' => '82',
    2 => '82',
    'job_createdby' => 'Administrator',
    3 => 'Administrator',
    'job_createdate' => '2020-05-16',
    4 => '2020-05-16',
    'job_duedate' => '2020-06-01',
    5 => '2020-06-01',
    'job_status' => '1',
    6 => '1',
    'job_priority' => '1',
    7 => '1',
    'job_type' => '1',
    8 => '1',
    'job_assignedto' => 'Garry Law',
    9 => 'Garry Law',
    'job_completedate' => NULL,
    10 => NULL,
    'job_notes' => NULL,
    11 => NULL,
    'booking_id' => '9',
    12 => '9',
    'bookingstarttime' => '11:00:00',
    13 => '11:00:00',
    'bookingendtime' => '13:00:00',
    14 => '13:00:00',
    'bookingdate' => '2020-06-01',
    15 => '2020-06-01',
    'asset_jobid' => '11',
    16 => '11',
    17 => '1',
    'engineer_id' => '1',
    18 => '1',
    'bookingstatus' => '1',
    19 => '1',
    'invoice_item_id' => '9',
    20 => '9',
    'company_id' => '1',
    21 => '1',
    22 => 'CADB-UK-0001',
    'companyname' => 'Example Company',
    23 => 'Example Company',
    'companyaddress1' => 'Example House',
    24 => 'Example House',
    'companyaddress2' => 'Example Street',
    25 => 'Example Street',
    'companyaddresscity' => 'Example City',
    26 => 'Example City',
    'companyaddresspostcode' => 'EX1 C12',
    27 => 'EX1 C12',
    'companytelephone' => '01234 567 890',
    28 => '01234 567 890',
    'companysector' => 'Example Sector',
    29 => 'Example Sector',
    'billingid' => '1',
    30 => '1',
    'company_contactname' => 'Mr Example Contact',
    31 => 'Mr Example Contact',
    'company_contactposition' => 'Head Of IT',
    32 => 'Head Of IT',
    'asset_id' => '11',
    33 => '11',
    'assetcompanyid' => 'CADB-UK-0001',
    34 => 'CADB-UK-0001',
    'assetname' => 'HP 280 G3',
    35 => 'HP 280 G3',
    'assettype' => '2',
    36 => '2',
    'assetmodel' => '280 G3',
    37 => '280 G3',
    'assetmake' => 'HP',
    38 => 'HP',
    'assetlocation' => '4',
    39 => '4',
    'assetstatus' => '1',
    40 => '1',
    'assetlastcheck' => '2020-01-14 00:00:00',
    41 => '2020-01-14 00:00:00',
    'assetSerialNumber' => NULL,
    42 => NULL,
    'assettag' => 'TESTCOMPANY-PC4',
    43 => 'TESTCOMPANY-PC4',
    'assetpurchasedate' => '2019-08-06 00:00:00',
    44 => '2019-08-06 00:00:00',
    'locationid' => '4',
    45 => '4',
    46 => 'CADB-UK-0001',
    'location_name' => 'Head Office',
    47 => 'Head Office',
    'location_room' => 'Marketing',
    48 => 'Marketing',
    'location_notes' => NULL,
    49 => NULL,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'assetjobid' => '12',
    0 => '12',
    'companyid' => 'CADB-UK-0001',
    1 => 'CADB-UK-0001',
    'assetid' => '77',
    2 => '77',
    'job_createdby' => 'Administrator',
    3 => 'Administrator',
    'job_createdate' => '2020-05-15',
    4 => '2020-05-15',
    'job_duedate' => '2020-06-03',
    5 => '2020-06-03',
    'job_status' => '1',
    6 => '1',
    'job_priority' => '1',
    7 => '1',
    'job_type' => '1',
    8 => '1',
    'job_assignedto' => 'Garry Law',
    9 => 'Garry Law',
    'job_completedate' => NULL,
    10 => NULL,
    'job_notes' => NULL,
    11 => NULL,
    'booking_id' => '10',
    12 => '10',
    'bookingstarttime' => '13:00:00',
    13 => '13:00:00',
    'bookingendtime' => '15:00:00',
    14 => '15:00:00',
    'bookingdate' => '2020-06-03',
    15 => '2020-06-03',
    'asset_jobid' => '12',
    16 => '12',
    17 => '1',
    'engineer_id' => '1',
    18 => '1',
    'bookingstatus' => '1',
    19 => '1',
    'invoice_item_id' => '10',
    20 => '10',
    'company_id' => '1',
    21 => '1',
    22 => 'CADB-UK-0001',
    'companyname' => 'Example Company',
    23 => 'Example Company',
    'companyaddress1' => 'Example House',
    24 => 'Example House',
    'companyaddress2' => 'Example Street',
    25 => 'Example Street',
    'companyaddresscity' => 'Example City',
    26 => 'Example City',
    'companyaddresspostcode' => 'EX1 C12',
    27 => 'EX1 C12',
    'companytelephone' => '01234 567 890',
    28 => '01234 567 890',
    'companysector' => 'Example Sector',
    29 => 'Example Sector',
    'billingid' => '1',
    30 => '1',
    'company_contactname' => 'Mr Example Contact',
    31 => 'Mr Example Contact',
    'company_contactposition' => 'Head Of IT',
    32 => 'Head Of IT',
    'asset_id' => '12',
    33 => '12',
    'assetcompanyid' => 'CADB-UK-0001',
    34 => 'CADB-UK-0001',
    'assetname' => 'HP 280 G3',
    35 => 'HP 280 G3',
    'assettype' => '2',
    36 => '2',
    'assetmodel' => '280 G3',
    37 => '280 G3',
    'assetmake' => 'HP',
    38 => 'HP',
    'assetlocation' => '5',
    39 => '5',
    'assetstatus' => '1',
    40 => '1',
    'assetlastcheck' => '2020-01-14 00:00:00',
    41 => '2020-01-14 00:00:00',
    'assetSerialNumber' => NULL,
    42 => NULL,
    'assettag' => 'TESTCOMPANY-PC5',
    43 => 'TESTCOMPANY-PC5',
    'assetpurchasedate' => '2019-08-06 00:00:00',
    44 => '2019-08-06 00:00:00',
    'locationid' => '5',
    45 => '5',
    46 => 'CADB-UK-0001',
    'location_name' => 'Head Office',
    47 => 'Head Office',
    'location_room' => 'Sales',
    48 => 'Sales',
    'location_notes' => NULL,
    49 => NULL,
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'assetjobid' => '13',
    0 => '13',
    'companyid' => 'CADB-UK-0001',
    1 => 'CADB-UK-0001',
    'assetid' => '110',
    2 => '110',
    'job_createdby' => 'Administrator',
    3 => 'Administrator',
    'job_createdate' => '2020-05-01',
    4 => '2020-05-01',
    'job_duedate' => '2020-06-05',
    5 => '2020-06-05',
    'job_status' => '1',
    6 => '1',
    'job_priority' => '2',
    7 => '2',
    'job_type' => '1',
    8 => '1',
    'job_assignedto' => 'Garry Law',
    9 => 'Garry Law',
    'job_completedate' => NULL,
    10 => NULL,
    'job_notes' => NULL,
    11 => NULL,
    'booking_id' => '11',
    12 => '11',
    'bookingstarttime' => '09:00:00',
    13 => '09:00:00',
    'bookingendtime' => '11:00:00',
    14 => '11:00:00',
    'bookingdate' => '2020-06-05',
    15 => '2020-06-05',
    'asset_jobid' => '13',
    16 => '13',
    17 => '1',
    'engineer_id' => '1',
    18 => '1',
    'bookingstatus' => '1',
    19 => '1',
    'invoice_item_id' => '11',
    20 => '11',
    'company_id' => '1',
    21 => '1',
    22 => 'CADB-UK-0001',
    'companyname' => 'Example Company',
    23 => 'Example Company',
    'companyaddress1' => 'Example House',
    24 => 'Example House',
    'companyaddress2' => 'Example Street',
    25 => 'Example Street',
    'companyaddresscity' => 'Example City',
    26 => 'Example City',
    'companyaddresspostcode' => 'EX1 C12',
    27 => 'EX1 C12',
    'companytelephone' => '01234 567 890',
    28 => '01234 567 890',
    'companysector' => 'Example Sector',
    29 => 'Example Sector',
    'billingid' => '1',
    30 => '1',
    'company_contactname' => 'Mr Example Contact',
    31 => 'Mr Example Contact',
    'company_contactposition' => 'Head Of IT',
    32 => 'Head Of IT',
    'asset_id' => '13',
    33 => '13',
    'assetcompanyid' => 'CADB-UK-0001',
    34 => 'CADB-UK-0001',
    'assetname' => 'HP 280 G3',
    35 => 'HP 280 G3',
    'assettype' => '2',
    36 => '2',
    'assetmodel' => '280 G3',
    37 => '280 G3',
    'assetmake' => 'HP',
    38 => 'HP',
    'assetlocation' => '5',
    39 => '5',
    'assetstatus' => '1',
    40 => '1',
    'assetlastcheck' => '2020-01-14 00:00:00',
    41 => '2020-01-14 00:00:00',
    'assetSerialNumber' => NULL,
    42 => NULL,
    'assettag' => 'TESTCOMPANY-PC6',
    43 => 'TESTCOMPANY-PC6',
    'assetpurchasedate' => '2019-08-06 00:00:00',
    44 => '2019-08-06 00:00:00',
    'locationid' => '5',
    45 => '5',
    46 => 'CADB-UK-0001',
    'location_name' => 'Head Office',
    47 => 'Head Office',
    'location_room' => 'Sales',
    48 => 'Sales',
    'location_notes' => NULL,
    49 => NULL,
  )
```

$bookingRes is the output from the PDO Query that fetches the records for the booked slots within the date range requested by FullCalendar.

**Further Edit**

I thought it might be of use if you could also see what $freeSlots consists of:

```
      array (
  1 => 
  array (
    'start' => '09:00',
    'end' => '11:00',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'start' => '11:00',
    'end' => '13:00',
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'start' => '13:00',
    'end' => '15:00',
  ),
  4 => 
  array (
    'start' => '15:00',
    'end' => '17:00',
  ),
)
```

Comment: I outlined the variables in bold mate to explain them

Comment: i have added them to the question to make it easier to go through and find any errors :)

Comment: yes, I noticed :), but cannot verify if that condition works as expected, hence the question. Did you sufficiently test the condition(s) you're using?

Comment: yes i have added echos for each of the conditions and printed the conditions and the dates have matched from database and the one that im checking against, and the slots also from database and the array matched. i cant figure out why they are repeating booked slots with free ones aswell

Comment: Without seeing the contents of `$bookingRes` it's going to be quite hard to help with this. Please can you add a suitable output of that. Please can you show the output using the [var_export](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php) command so that the data can be easily re-used in a demo environment. Debugging this code is going to be the only way to fix it.

Comment: P.S. Why do all of them say 9.00-11.00 or 13.00-15.00 _twice_? Are there two available slots in each time period? It would just be helpful to understand that. I am wondering if potentially this has something to do with your problem.

Comment: @ADyson the duplication is the issue im facing, i dont want it to show a free slot when there is a booking there

Comment: looking at it a little bit further, in Month View, it shows 3 of each slot free, i think this is beacuse there are 3 booked slots in the date range and its doing the free slots 3 times :( what a headache this is lol

Comment: Thanks for the update, but can you specifically provide the data using the [var_export](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php) command as I requested before? It makes it much easier to import the data into another PHP environment - with var_export output you can just paste it into another script and it's valid syntax. That doesn't work with var_dump or print_r output.

Comment: ive edited the outputs for you :)

Comment: Looking at the code last night, I was looping through all the available slots inside a loop for the database results, thus creating however many database results worth of each slot. I need to rethink the coding approach

Comment: if you  use the timeGrid view, and just leave the available slots empty as I've suggested before, if you then set the slot duration to two hours, and start the day at 9, end at 5, then you don't really need a list of free slots at all, they just "exist" as the empty spaces on the calendar. Then the user can select them, and they won't be able to select anything that's already booked. here's the bare bones of such an approach: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/bGEdqWe

Comment: @ADyson thanks, but i really need to show the user the free slots so they can click on one to select it for a booking. im going to rethink the whole approach to free slots, there is a way to do it, i just need to be more practical :) thanks for the help tho :)

Comment: Did you actually look at my demo? Those free spaces are selectable...that's the whole point. Watch the console when you click them, the "select" callback fires and logs the time that was clicked. Then you can add in some code however you please to handle making the booking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to thank @ADyson for his help with the issues I have faced using FullCalendar.

I have, however, completed the task that i needed to do.

The way that i approached it was:

1. Create a array of available slots within 1 day.
2. Create a new array of available slots within the requested date range, creating a new
   array with the fields **date**, **start**, **end**, **isbooked**.

   Now I have an array with slot times and dates for the whole requested date range, the last issue I faced was how am I going to go through this in a foreach loop and change the original value? I stumbled on another answer on StackOverflow that answered that question for me and thus, i was able to do a final foreach loop on the final array, and loop though each database result to check if it matched the date on the timeslot the foreach was showing and then set the **isbooked** flag to true.

Finally! I had a working set of code that created the JSON return I needed. NO Duplicates, just free slots and booked slots sitting together nicely.

The final code I had is as follows:

```
    for ( $i = 0; $i <= $daysInRange; $i++ ) {

    //for the current date we need to go through each slot. 
    foreach ( $freeSlots as $slot ) {

        $slotStart = new DateTime( $slot[ 'start' ] );
        $slotEnd = new DateTime( $slot[ 'end' ] );



                $aSlot[ 'date' ] = $cDate->format( "Y-m-d" );
                $aSlot[ 'start' ] = $slotStart->format( "H:i:s" );
                $aSlot[ 'end' ] = $slotEnd->format( "H:i:s" );
                $aSlot[ 'isbooked' ] = false;
                $allSlots[] = $aSlot;   


    }



    //Now add 1 day to the cDate and then check if its greater than the eDate
    $cDate->modify( '+1 Day' );
    if ( $cDate > $eDate ) {
        break;
    }

}
//var_export($allSlots);
#check new array against database and mark booked slots 
foreach($allSlots as &$slot){

    foreach($bookingResult as $booking) {

        if($booking['bookingdate'] == $slot['date'] && $booking['bookingstarttime'] == $slot['start'] && $booking['bookingendtime'] == $slot['end']){
            $slot['isbooked'] = true;
        }

    }

}
//Now booked slots are marked we can now create the JSON.
foreach ( $allSlots as $slot ) {

    $slotStart = new DateTime( $slot[ 'start' ] );
    $slotEnd = new DateTime( $slot[ 'end' ] );
    $slotDate = new DateTime( $slot[ 'date' ] );


    if ( $slot[ 'isbooked' ] == false ) {
        $bookingsAsJSON[ 'title' ] = 'Unbooked Timeslot';
        $bookingsAsJSON[ 'start' ] = $slotDate->format("Y-m-d"). ' ' . $slotStart->format( "H:i:s" );
        $bookingsAsJSON[ 'end' ] = $slotDate->format( "Y-m-d" ) . ' ' . $slotEnd->format( "H:i:s" );
        $bookingsAsJSON[ 'extendedProps' ][ 'bookingActualDate' ] = $slotDate->format( "Y-m-d" );
        $bookingsAsJSON[ 'extendedProps' ][ 'bookingActualStartTime' ] = $slotStart->format( "H:i:s" );
        $bookingsAsJSON[ 'extendedProps' ][ 'bookingActualEndTime' ] = $slotEnd->format( "H:i:s" );
        $calendarEvents[] = $bookingsAsJSON;
    }
}
```

The output on the calendar looked like this:

[image: Output screenshot]